# Exact structure of flattened object in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I know there are a lot of similar questions, and I have looked through a whole lot of them, but haven't managed to figure this out.

If I have:

```
public class ClientRoot
{
  public Client client { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Client
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  ...
```

as my Source, and the Dto is:
public class ClientDto

```
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  ...
```

Am I understanding correctly that AutoMapper should be able to flatten this automatically without me writing any custom mapping? And should the property in the dto be called *name* or *clientname* ?

I am getting a null return either way when I do:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ClientRoot, ClientDto>());
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
...
ClientDto dto = mapper.Map<ClientRoot, ClientDto>(c); // c is a valid ClientRoot instance
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to achieve. The code it self needs a little work, and appreciate that, but what is the type of flattened data, is it s csv file, txt file, excel and so on...  I suspect you need to read it in and transform it to an object before you can do any mapping on it.  I could be wrong, but I need a little more context

Comment: Sure, thanks - I need a flat object so that I can create a single SQL table from it. So rather than have an object c.client.name (which is what I receive via API)  i need something more like c.name

Comment: Sorry, never saw your reply until now.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flattening would be used if `ClientDto` was

```
public class ClientDto
{
    public string clientName { get; set; }
}
```

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html

> Classic flattening doesn’t require a map for the child type.

Comment: Thanks Martin - so `clientName` in camelCase? I'm not sure I understand why client is lowercase and Name is uppercase in the Dto

Comment: Splitting destination property names is done using PascalCase convention. For example. if the property in `ClientDto` was named `clientnAme`, it would not be mapped.

Comment: Thanks, but if destination must be PascalCase - surely the property should be ClientName in your answer, not clientName?

Comment: yes, it looks Automapper tests both PascalCase and camelCase.

Comment: Thanks! It worked if I changed to either ClientName or clientName

Comment: Guys, but you did also check `IncludeMembers` and prefered it this way, right? :)